# How to find unique values in one data frame and use it to filter another data frame in R

Tags: r, filter

I have two data frames (bmdat1, plots1) that are referencing the same experiment. I need to find the unique values from plots1$Bucket and use them to filter the second data frame by the unique values in plots1#Bucket.

Here is what I have tried

```
bm1dat1 <- filter(bmdat1, bucket == as.vector(unique(plots1$Bucket)))
```

This returns

```
Warning messages:
1: In `==.default`(bucket, as.vector(unique(plots1$Bucket))) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I have also tried

```
bm1dat1 <- filter(bmdat1, bucket == unique(plots1$Bucket))
```

and I recieved

```
Error in Ops.factor(bucket, unique(plots1$Bucket)) : 
  level sets of factors are different
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `%in%` to check that elements on the set on the left are present in the set on the right (this is what it sounds like you are trying to do). This should work, but don't know since we don't have a sample of your data to work with.

```r
bm1dat1 <- filter(bmdat1, bucket %in% unique(plots1$Bucket))
```